# Private SSH keys being exposed in wp-admin plugin settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, ssh-keys

I'm a designer with development experience who's keeping an eye on progress of a custom plugin for the client. Today the developer asked for feedback, and concerned with the following:

Essentially the plugin being built syncs the database of WooCommerce 6,000+ products with Google Sheets (using clients business G-Suite) - on inspection, I'm concerned to see that the developer has exposed their private keys on the frontend of wp-admin settings, with no plans to hide or obscure as the plugin needs ability for this to be updated.

Concern is that all this information is will be exposed to 30+ staff plus contributers and other developers, and while I'm confident nobody in organisation would abuse I'm just worried about other possibilities - and how attainable this data could be via possible unauthorized methods.

Am I paranoid? If not then how insecure/bad is this being that this SSH key gives admin/owner access to Google Cloud Compute Engine as well as business GSuite access.

Needing to have confident knowledge when speaking to developer who usually ignores.

Thank you anyone who can advise.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114487/why-does-wordpress-need-my-private-ssh-key-to-update

Comment: Why don't you ask the developer to hide the private key fields (or the whole plugin options page) from average users and have the key(s) just available to Admin? If you can't trust the other users then this would make sense

Comment: You could even use a plugin such as https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/ for this

Comment: @MatthewB thanks for replying, yes I am aware of adminimize etc and would definitely use this - though my question if by having the private key totally visible in a meta field, would this also make it attainable in other ways. In my few years of WordPress I&amp;#39;ve never seen a plugin require a private SSH key, let alone having the key remain exposed via a field.

Comment: @MatthewB I'm also thinking long-term, e.g if I'm not around to manage securing that field and other accounts are created etc, people come and go and the client isn't technically minded.

Comment: I'm not sure what the private SSH key is used for - could you confirm? You could always change the input field itself to a 'password' field so that it get starred out, however this could still then be obtained by other means.